# Constructing std::regex from a char* slice, without copy

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm working with some C++11 code, I have raw C character pointer (`char const * const`), and I want to make a std::regex from a specific section of it (a slice of the memory).

I could construct a `std::string` from the pointer's memory slice, and cause a heap allocation, but I'm hoping to avoid this.

The std::regex's constructor's second parameter is a set of regex bit flags, not a length to read.

Is there a good solution for this, given that I am trying to reduce memory copies?

The constructor can accept a char iterator, can that solve this?

Comment: `std::regex` does have a constructor taking pointer and length, as well as one taking a pair of iterators (a pair of `char*` pointers would work there). Overloads (3) and (7) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah, yes, (3) works, not sure if that'll overlap with (2), but it should work fne.